Site Dynamics: Any need for changes
The moderator election gave me pause to reflect on how the site has changed across time. Here are some purely descriptive graphics
Posts: all and questions

Using Anton Antonov's QuantileRegression: the median, 5th and  95 th percentile of weekly post count:

The data source is from here:
Dynamics of top ten users reputations

I am not a top 10 user but reference.
I  adapted code from here.
Question
There has been a drop in site use and top user paticipation has a complex bidirectional relationship with this.
These changes are almost certainly multifactorial (including factors relating to all Stack Exchanges, changes in  Wolfram Language/Mathematica,  user interests, time and circumstances.
My question, in the context of new moderators, are there strategies or tactics that can encourage new user retention, old user participation? As an entirely personal and subjective perspective I perceive a loss of "fun", creative engagement and friendly respectful iterative answer evolution. This may be just me. I am not part of any cliques but have extremely valued the diverse creativity of this community.
Others with time and greater skills may delve deeper into the analytics and get real insights rather than these superficial observations.
I am soon to have a major surgical procedure (with a, thankfully low,  mortality) and just wanted to ask this.
Anyway,  see you on the other side.
Update
Survived operation: now long recovery ✌️

Oh it's painful for me to write long text in English so let me be short: according to my experience, personal effort won't have much effect on the… popularity of a site. (It will have effect on the… atmosphere to some degree, though. ) So…let it be, no need to worry (in every sense :D )! Good luck!

To get a better understanding, your graph should probably be compared to the overall statistics of StackExchange (example). Then it will probably turned out that there is nothing in particular "wrong" about MMA SE ... :)

@Domen Of course you are right. I don’t think there is anything “wrong”with the site (more my perception) and I still learn and benefit from it. I posted this, somewhat, provocative question , not to insult anyone or the site. On reflection it is a stupid question. I think I hoped new moderators may be opportunity for reflection of user communication/behaviour etc.

@xzczd I agree that it is unlikely individual  user efforts is unlikely to change global trends. Further, one of the site’s strengths has been user diversity and creativity and generally civility: so there is not much more a user can do. Thank you for good wishes .

@ubpdqn, no no, it's a great question! I was typing quickly and didn't find a more appropriate word than 'wrong' :)

If compared to two similar sites, StackOverflow and Mathematics SE, MMA is actually doing better than the the other two in recent years! :)

@Domen importance of looking deeper than my superficial perception. Thank you!

may be people are using AI now to generate code (and answer other questions) and they do not need to ask as many questions on stackexchange sites? Over 25% of Google’s code is now written by AI

A large proportion of questions already have good answers.  If people are finding these, rather than asking new questions, that's a good thing.  Improvements in Mathematica have probably reduced the number of common traps that new users fall into.


Congrats for surviving the operation! 2. Random thought: my rep is not even a blip in the top-ten users plot :D 3. I work in a very numerics/calculations demanding lab and unfortunately we have all moved to other languages (Python etc). Alas, now I only use Mathematica when some symbolic-numeric combo is needed and that is becoming rarer and rarer. 4. As others mentioned, there's already a plethora of tons of good answers to most common problems. Just my 4 cents!


Congrats. Maybe it’s the very obsession with reputation score that ruins fun? I.e. having fun thinking up the best answer is totally different from chasing the highest rep score, as fast as possible.
